How can I calculate the zeros and poles of a Type II error amplifier if the op-amp is non-ideal? FACT? How?
I would like to examine the effect of the op-amp's \$A_{OL}\$ and low-frequency \$\omega_p\$ on the Type II error amplifier.
I have managed to determine the transfer function, but how can I calculate the poles and zeros? The transfer function is very complex, third-order. I believe the FACT technique might simplify the process, but how should I account for the op-amp's pole during the calculations?
Without going into detailed calculations, the results are:


I would recommend you look at this 2-part article I published in How2Power some time ago. It studies the op-amp impact on the compensator response. I also used the FACTs in a type 3 analysis here.

When you try to analyze a circuit (as shown) for a real gain Aol, you should take into account also the fact that each opamp needs DC feedback for a stable operational point. But independent on this, your approach seems to be OK. Insert the function Z(s) and evaluate the ratio Ve/Vi.

@LvW: Thank you for your response!
If I understand correctly, since this is essentially an integrator, it amplifies at DC: $\epsilon \cdot A_{OL}$ . Or is that not what you meant?
If I substitute, a complex transfer function arises, and my problem is that I cannot determine the roots of the denominator, because the equation will be third-order. So, I could plot the function, but I wouldn't be able to determine the component values this way :/

@ slimcolt - are you interested in the results only or do you want to see a detailed calculation for poles and zeroes? In the first case, each symbolic simulator can give you the requested information.

@Verbal Kint Thank you very much! Your publications have answered my question.
https://www.how2power.com/pdf_view.php?url=/newsletters/1702/articles/H2PToday1702_design_ONSemi.pdf
